# How to use the Comparator interface in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I can't figure out how to properly use the Comparator interface.

NOTE: I don't want to use the "one line" comparator implementation I see on most code, meaning :

```
Collections.sort(deck, new Comparator<Card>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Card o1, Card o2) {
   return WHATEVER;
  });
```

Again, I don't want to use this, because I'm going to be sorting many different ArrayLists and it seems like a waste of space to do that every time. I want to somehow make it work, having my compareTo method written once in one place.

I tried many different things, but I'm new to implementing interfaces, so I'm probably missing something.

This is my Card class with it's compare method. (NOTE: Let me save you some time and say that I'm not interested in using Enumerations to simplify the code and the comparison, I just want to learn how to use Comparator properly. I know it looks bad but I have to use some already written code. )

```
import java.util.*;
public class Card implements Comparator<Card>
{
    private String number;
    private int value;
    private int finalValue;
    private String suit;
    private Player owner;

    public Card(String number, String suit)
    {
        this.number=number;
        switch (number){
            case "2": this.value = 2;
                break;
            case "3": this.value = 3;
                break;
            case "4": this.value = 4;
                break;
            case "5": this.value = 5;
                break;    
            case "6": this.value = 6;
                break;
            case "7": this.value = 7;
                break;
            case "8": this.value = 8;
                break;    
            case "9": this.value = 9;
                break;
            case "10": this.value = 10;
                break;
            case "J": this.value = 11;
                break;
            case "Q": this.value = 12;
                break;
            case "K": this.value = 13;
                break;
            case "A": this.value = 14;
                break;
            }

        this.suit=suit;
        switch (suit){
            case "Spades": this.finalValue = this.value*4;
                break;
            case "Hearts": this.finalValue = this.value*5;
                break;
            case "Clubs": this.finalValue = this.value*2;
                break;
            case "Diamonds": this.finalValue = this.value*3;
                break;
            }
    }

    public int compare(Card card1, Card card2)
    {
        Integer suitValue1;
        if (card1.getSuit() == "Hearts")
        suitValue1=5;
        else if (card1.getSuit() == "Spades")
        suitValue1=4;
        else if (card1.getSuit() == "Diamonds")
        suitValue1=3;
        else
        suitValue1=2;

        Integer suitValue2;
        if (card2.getSuit() == "Hearts")
        suitValue2=5;
        else if (card2.getSuit() == "Spades")
        suitValue2=4;
        else if (card2.getSuit() == "Diamonds")
        suitValue2=3;
        else
        suitValue2=2;

        Integer value1, value2;
        value1 = card1.getValue();
        value2 = card2.getValue();

        if (suitValue1 != suitValue2)
        return suitValue1.compareTo(suitValue2);
        else
        return value1.compareTo(value2);

    }

    //get methods
    public int getValue()
    {return this.value;}

    public int getFinalValue()
    {return this.finalValue;}

    public String getNumber()
    {return this.number;}

    public String getSuit()
    {return this.suit;}

    public Player getOwner()
    {return this.owner;}

    //set methods
    public void setValue(int value)
    {this.value = value;}

    public void setFinalValue(int finalValue)
    {this.finalValue = finalValue;}

    public void setNumber(String number)
    {this.number = number;}

    public void setSuit(String suit)
    {this.suit = suit;}

    public void setOwner(Player player)
    {this.owner = player;}

}
```

So that's my compare method. Should I put it in another class or something? I try to call it using this:

```
Collections.sort(deck, new Comparator<Card>());
```

but that is obviously wrong.

deck is an ArrayList : `private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();` filled with various Card objects.

Comment: Use equals method for String comparison instead of ==/

Comment: You're confusing `Comparator<T>` and `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, you haven't got a compareTo method here, you've got a compare. Comparator != Comparable

Comment: Although the say you hyave it in your question, it would work to do something like `Collections.sort(deck, deck.get(0));`. (This is still not something you _should_ do though.)

Comment: @JonKiparsky You're right, nothing a sneaky edit can't fix tho!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `Comparable` with `Comparator`. They are similar of course but really fundamentally different.

`Comparable` defines the natural ordering of a class--how instances of your class should sort themselves by default. That's actually what you want here.

`Comparator` helps you to sort the instances of your class when you want to use a different sort order than the natural order. That doesn't seem to be your aim here.

So what you actually want is this:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
  public int compareTo(Card otherCard) {
    //return 1 when this instance is greater than the parameter, -1 if less; 0 if equal
  } 

  //Other stuff
  //And make sure compareTo is consistent with equals
}
```

Note that the method you have to implement is `compareTo`, which is different from what you implement with `Comparator`.

Then you simply sort this way:

```
Collections.sort(deck)
```

And the cards will know how to sort themselves.

If you need more guidance, we actually did a [tutorial](http://www.vidyasource.com/tutorial/Programming/Java/2013/10/27/comparison-shopping) on `Comparable` and `Comparator` with the files available on [Github](https://github.com/VidyaSource/comparison-shopping). Check it out if you like.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial, it helped tons. It gave me a new idea for another part of my code and I will be using Comparator after all since it will open up new scoring options for my card game! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project! It looks fun.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have one only way to compare Card objects, you don't really have to use a Comparator.  Let Card implement Comparable, instead, and then sort by the 1-parameter method:

```
Collections.sort(deck);
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize:

- To sort the array use [Collections.sort(deck);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
- Your Card class needs to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- When comparing Strings its best to use equals
- It is better to use the constant String first ie "Hearts".equals(this.getSuit()), this will guard against Null pointers

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement Comparable, and then you can just sort the array.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Juned, use value1.equals(value2) this returns a boolean.  From the looks of things you only doing string comparison which is fairly stright forward.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you intended. I don't believe you can use a switch statement on Strings unless you are 1.7+

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>
{
    private String number;
    private int value;
    private int finalValue;
    private String suit;
    private Player owner;

    public Card(String number, String suit)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.value = 0;
        this.finalValue = 0;


        //card value
        if ("2".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 2;
        }
        else if ("3".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 3;

        }
        else if ("4".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 4;

        }
        else if ("5".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 5;

        }
        else if ("6".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 6;

        }
        else if ("7".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 7;

        }
        else if ("8".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 8;

        }
        else if ("9".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 9;
        }
        else if ("10".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 10;
        }
        else if ("J".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 11;

        }
        else if ("Q".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 12;
        }
        else if ("K".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 13;

        }
        else if ("A".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.value = 14;
        }


        //suits
        if ("Spades".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.finalValue = this.value * 4;
        }
        else if ("Hearts".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.finalValue = this.value * 5;

        }
        else if ("Clubs".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.finalValue = this.value * 2;

        }
        else if ("Diamonds".equalsIgnoreCase(number))
        {
            this.finalValue = this.value * 3;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card o)
    {
        final int EQUAL = 0;
        final int LESS_THAN = -1;
        final int GREATER_THAN = 1;

        if (this == o || this.getFinalValue() == o.getFinalValue())
        {
            return EQUAL;
        }
        else if (this.getFinalValue() < o.getFinalValue())
        {
            return LESS_THAN;
        }
        else
        {
            return GREATER_THAN;
        }
    }

    // get methods
    public int getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public int getFinalValue()
    {
        return this.finalValue;
    }

    public String getNumber()
    {
        return this.number;
    }

    public String getSuit()
    {
        return this.suit;
    }

    public Player getOwner()
    {
        return this.owner;
    }

    // set methods
    public void setValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setFinalValue(int finalValue)
    {
        this.finalValue = finalValue;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setSuit(String suit)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public void setOwner(Player player)
    {
        this.owner = player;
    }
}
```